# Use Azure CLI to generate function class library

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I've noticed I generate a different folder structure and file extensions for C# code depending on whether I use the the Azure CLI (folder with a .csx script library) or Visual studio (no folder with a .cs class library). Debugging from the CLI only exposes the .csx endpoints and visa-versa from Visual Studio.

Is it possible to configure the Azure CLI to generate functions using class libraries? Or so that the CLI and Visual Studio provide the same debugging endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible now. We have few asks for it and will add it at some point, issue to track:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/382